# Examples of non-positively Curvature Riemannian Manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, riemannian-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, information-geometry

When I read about complete, simply connected, and connected Riemannian manifolds of non-positive curvature I only find explicit examples of hyperbolic $n$-space and Euclidean space.  What are other commonly used spaces meeting these criteria?

I'm interested in two types of "applications"

1. Used within differential geometry.

   - In this case, I'm most interested in examples of *symmetric spaces of non-compact* type besides $H^n$ and *symmetric positive-definite matrices*.
   - Some concrete examples of non-constant and non-positive curvature would be nice.
2. Examples of geometries used in statistics, and applied sciences

   - Gaussian densities I already know about  ( which really follows from the former + some information geometric considerations).
   - *I leave this up to interpretation, besides saying I'd like to gain some concrete use with my audience.  So the hyperboloid example, from the comments, is nice but the examples of symmetric PSD matrices above is more reflective of what I am aiming for.*

**Edit:**  I added some comments following Moishe Kohan's remarks and certain other comments.

*Thought: I guess we can always generate more "explicit" examples as follows: given any $\phi \in Diff(M,N)$, where $(M,g_M)$ is either of $\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{H}^n$, space of symmetric positive definite matrices,* and $N$ is some smooth manifold diffeomorphic to $M$, then $g_N:=\phi_{\star}(g_M)$ will give us a non-positively curved Riemannian structure on $N$, since $g_N$ is [conformal](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.jdg/1214431798) to $g_M$...  Though a direct construction of an example like this is a bit...underwhelming.*

Comment: You certainly don't need constant curvature. So consider surfaces like saddle surfaces or hyperboloids of one sheet in $\Bbb R^3$.

Comment: Yes but are these actually used outside differential geometry?

Comment: @MrMMS: Your comment is rather vague and is not implied by the stated criterion of "commonly used". Perhaps you want to update your question to clarify your criteria?

Comment: "Actually used"? Well, a hyperboloid of one sheet, being a (doubly) ruled surface, is very stable, in terms of structural engineering, and the shape is sometimes used in "the real world" for that reason. Saddle surfaces are used on horses; perhaps your horses are geometrically-inclined, but ...

Comment: @TedShifrin Ahaha I like the saddle example!  But yes the hyperboloid example is interesting.

Comment: Universal covering space of a connected compact Riemannian manifold of nonpositive curvature always meets your criteria. As for applications, it depends. Most interesting applications are in the setting of singular metrics. Also, symmetric spaces of noncompact type such as the space of positive definite matrices. How many examples do you need?

Comment: Actually, I used the positive definite matrices example in my paper (now that you mention it), as well as the space of Gaussian measures, and some submanifolds of the Wasserstein-2 space.  Honestly, something from symmetric spaces would be fantastic.

Comment: As far as I know, those are the constant curvature examples.  Just as the sphere is the only constant positive curvature example.  So there's good reason for the emphasis.  I think they're called space forms, but I may have forgotten.

Comment: @ChrisCuster  Right, but I'm not restricting to constant curvature examples.

Comment: Obviously not.  And I didn't mean to be captain obvious.  But it's like a uniformization theorem, or categorisation and one of the main things to learn.  I'm sure you learned it.  Carry on!

Comment: I will write down an answer to the question about examples. However, the question about applications I do not understand: Metrics with special curvature properties (their existence, uniqueness, structure, etc.) are a (rather classical) **subject of study** of Riemannian geometry. Asking about their applications in RG is akin to asking about applications of Diophantine  equations in number theory. Maybe "application" is just a wrong choice of word.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I added some clarifications as to what I know and what I'm looking for.  If it helps guide the specific answers.

Comment: Any hypersurface in projective space of high enough degree is another example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If and when I have more time, I will add further details, the following is just a (pretty long) stub.

First of all, if $(M,g)$ is a complete connected Riemannian manifold of sectional curvature $\le 0$, then lifting $g$ to the universal covering of $M$ results in a **Hadamard manifold**, i.e. a complete simply connected Riemannian manifold of nonpositive curvature. Note that if $M$ is compact, the metric $g$ is automatically complete. Now, some examples:

1. If $(M_1, g_1), ...., (M_k,g_k)$ are Hadamard manifolds, so is their product $M_1\times ...\times M_k$ equipped with the product-metric
   $$
   g= g_1+...+g_k.
   $$

From this, you see that products of hyperbolic spaces and Euclidean spaces are Hadamard manifolds.

2. The direct product construction generalizes to certain *warped products* of manifolds of nonpositive curvature (provided that the warping function is convex), see

*Bishop, R. L.; O’Neill, B.*, [**Manifolds of negative curvature**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/1995057), Trans. Am. Math. Soc. 145, 1-49 (1969). [ZBL0191.52002](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0191.52002).

3. As an application of the warping construction M.Anderson proved in

*Anderson, Michael T.*, [**Metrics of negative curvature on vector bundles**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2046641), Proc. Am. Math. Soc. 99, 357-363 (1987). [ZBL0615.53025](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0615.53025).

that if $E\to M$ is a vector bundle over a manifold $M$ admitting a complete metric of nonpositive curvature, then $E$ also admits such a metric.

3. Metrics of nonpositive curvature are frequently constructed by **gluing** manifolds of nonpositive curvature (with totally-geodesic boundary!) along boundary, provided some boundary conditions are met. Using this, B.Leeb proved in

*Leeb, Bernhard*, [**3-manifolds with(out) metrics of nonpositive curvature**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01231445), Invent. Math. 122, No. 2, 277-289 (1995). [ZBL0840.53031](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0840.53031).

that "most" closed aspherical (i.e. with trivial higher homotopy groups) 3-manifolds admit metrics of nonpositive curvature. (Asphericity is clearly a necessary condition.)

4. There are constructions of (complete) metrics on nonpositive curvature on branched coverings over complete Riemannian manifolds of nonpositive curvature (again, provided some conditions on the branch-locus are met), see e.g.

*Gromov, Mikhael; Thurston, William P.*, [**Pinching constants for hyperbolic manifolds**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01404671), Invent. Math. 89, 1-12 (1987). [ZBL0646.53037](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0646.53037).

5. There are "cusp-closing" constructions of metric of nonpositive curvature (starting, say, with complete hyperbolic manifolds of finite volume), see e.g.

*Schroeder, Viktor*, [**A cusp closing theorem**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2047438), Proc. Am. Math. Soc. 106, No. 3, 797-802 (1989). [ZBL0678.53034](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0678.53034).

6. All *symmetric spaces of noncompact type* have nonpositive curvature. One can spend whole life studying these, see e.g.

*Helgason, Sigurdur*, Differential geometry, Lie groups, and symmetric spaces., Graduate Studies in Mathematics. 34. Providence, RI: American Mathematical Society (AMS). xxvi, 641 p. (2001). [ZBL0993.53002](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0993.53002).

The space $P_n$ of positive-definite symmetric $n\times n$ matrices  is just one example of a symmetric space of noncompact type. (Technically speaking, one needs to assume that the determinant equals 1, otherwise, you get the product of ${\mathbb R}$ with a symmetric space of noncompact type.) However, every  symmetric space of noncompact type admits an isometric totally-geodesic embeddings in $P_n$ for some $n$, so in this sense, $P_n$ is the main example. A famous algebraic application of nonpositive curvature of symmetric spaces is Cartan's Theorem:

*Let $G$ be a connected semisimple Lie group. Then all maximal compact subgroups of $G$ are conjugate to each other.*

In my answer I gave (with one exception) no explicit formulae, but all known constructions of metrics of nonpositive curvature are quite explicit. (I am not counting Ricci Flow in dimension 3, since limit metrics have constant curvature.)

As for *applications*, I still do not entirely understand the question. Having nonpositive curvature has various **implications** for topology of manifolds, especially their fundamental groups. Would you count decidability of the *word problem* (for $\pi_1$ of a compact manifold of nonpositive curvature) as an application? I would. As another example: If $M$ is a connected manifold which admits a complete metric of nonpositive curvature, then $\pi_1(M)$ satisfies *Novikov's Conjecture.* Another famous topological application is in work of Farrell and Jones on *Borel conjecture*.

Now, if you allow for singular metrics of nonpositive curvature (CAT(0) spaces) then there are applications in mathematical biology and mathematical physics, see e.g. my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3256658/nice-applications-of-cartan-hadamards-theorem/3257475#3257475).

**Edit.** Here is the sketch of a proof of Cartan's theorem. I think, it is Cartan's original argument. For details, see for instance Helgason's book listed above or

*Donaldson, Simon K.*, [**Lie algebra theory without algebra**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-0-8176-4745-2_12), Tschinkel, Yuri (ed.) et al., Algebra, arithmetic, and geometry. In honor of Yu. I. Manin on the occasion of his 70th birthday. Vol. I. Boston, MA: Birkhäuser (ISBN 978-0-8176-4744-5/hbk; 978-0-8176-4745-2/ebook). Progress in Mathematics 269, 549-566 (2009). [ZBL1198.22004](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1198.22004).

Step 1. Let $G$ be a connected semisimple real Lie group with finite center. Let $K$ be a maximal compact subgroup. Then the quotient $X=G/K$ is simply-connected and has a (left) $G$-invariant complete Riemannian metric of nonpositive curvature (coming from the Killing from on the Lie algebra ${\mathfrak g}$ of $G$ and the associated Cartajn decomposition of ${\mathfrak g}$). By the construction, $G$-stabilizers of points in $X$ are conjugate to $K$.

Step 2. Let $H\subset G$ be a compact subgroup. It acts isometrically on the Hadamard manifold $X$. One then proves:

**Theorem.** (Cartan's fixed point theorem) If $H$ is a compact group acting continuously and isometrically on a Hadamard manifold $X$, then $H$ fixes a point in $X$.

There are several arguments for proving this, all (that I know) boil down to taking an $H$-orbit $Hx$ in $X$ (which is bounded by compactness of $H$) and defining a "center" of  this orbit. This center is either the Chebyshev center (center of the smallest radius ball containing $Hx$)  or the barycenter of $Hx$. (This is where one uses nonpositive curvature.)

By the uniqueness and naturality of the center, it will be fixed by $H$.

Applying this to the symmetric space $X=G/K$, one concludes the proof of Cartan's theorem on maximal compact subgroups.

Comment: +1.. What do you meant by "One can spend whole life studying these" in 6? you meant they are so vast or so interesting?

Comment: +1. Is the "Cartan's Theorem" really a result of the non-positiveness of curvature of symmetric spaces? I like to see a proof of that. any reference?

Comment: @C.F.G: See the edit. Yes, symmetric spaces are vast and interesting. Helgason is a good example of a mathematician who spent his life studying symmetric spaces (he was most famous for harmonic analysis on symmetric spaces).

Comment: Amazing post Moishe!